# Change Font in KOMA \extratitle Command

Tags: koma-script

KOMA scrbook class.
I'd like to change the font on the half-title page, which is created by the \extratitle command.

Here is a MWE:

```
 %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
 %!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


  \documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\begin{document}

\newfontfamily\myfunt[Ligatures=TeX]{Papyrus}

\begingroup   %begin font change
\myfunt
%%% Here is where \extratitle begins

  \extratitle{\vspace*{18\baselineskip}
  \begin{center}\textbf{\Huge Great Title}\end{center}} 



  \endgroup  %%end font change




    \title{Great Title}
    \author{The Author}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
   \end{document}
```

When I compile this no errors are thrown, but the half title page doesn't use the Papyrus font. I've also tried changing the name to "Papyrus Regular" which throws a "File Not Found Error" and even "Papyrus.ttc" which is the fully name of the font in the Library/Fonts folder. This also throws a "File Not Found Error." Not sure if the issue is with .ttc fonts, Hoefler Text is a .ttc font as well and displays properly.

The related question (marked as identical) deals with font *size*, this question deals with the font *face*. The two are not identical and take different arguments.

Comment: Untested, place `\myfunt`  just before `Great Title`?

Comment: That worked! Odd that the \begingroup...\endgroup had no effect. Please make this an answer.

Comment: Why should it? You are just storing some strings with `\extratitle`. Nothing is printed or output. All that happens with `\maketitle`. Personally, i am not a big fan of those predefined titlepages that are hard to customize. I prefer: [How to customize my titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280)

Comment: You could use `\newkomafont{extratitle}{<font settings >}` in the preamble and then `\extratitle{\usekomafont{extratitle} <your extratitle>}`.

Comment: From a texnical point of view, those questions are exactly the same.

Comment: Why do you think that someone looking for assistance would assume or even think that a font face is the same as a font size? I linked the related question in the question.

Comment: Marking questions as duplicate is to have a better way of dealing with content for future users. If the same question is on site ten times, it needs to be updates ten times (if an update is needed). If all similar questions point to the same answer, just one update is needed. It is a system that tries to keep content dealable, so that many users in the future can benefit from it.