# Change Font Size in KOMA \extratitle command

Tags: fontsize, koma-script

Related question: [Change Font in KOMA \extratitle Command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359050/change-font-in-koma-extratitle-command)

KOMA scrbook class. I'd like to change the size of the font on the half-title page, which is created by the \extratitle command.

I only want the font size change to apply to the half-title page and not in the rest of the document. I thought I could do this by creating a new environment but this does not seem to work.

Here is a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

%\usepackage{moresize}  Can't get anything larger than HUGE
%\usepackage{relsize} scaling at 5x had no effect


 \begin{document}

 \newenvironment{zebratitle}{\changefontsizes{36pt}{\Huge}}

 \newfontfamily\myfunt[Ligatures=TeX]{Papyrus}

  \begin{zebratitle}
  \extratitle{\vspace*{5\baselineskip}

  \begin{center}\textbf{\Huge \myfunt Great Title}\end{center}} 

  \end{zebratitle}

  \title{Great Title}
  \author{The Author}
  \date{}
  \maketitle
   \end{document}
```

Comment: You should put `zebratitle` into the `\extratitle` as it changes the font sizes.

Comment: You could define a new font element `extratitle` in the preamble: `\newkomafont{extratitle}{<font settings >}`. Then this can be used in `\extratitle{\usekomafont{extratitle} <your extratitle>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- The `\changefontsizes` command takes only one argument. Your group with only `\Huge` does nothing at all.
- The `\extratitle` command is not affected by a group around it and prints only what is inside its argument. So you have to put `zebratitle` into `\extratitle`.

*Update:* Thanks to Schweinebacke I reworked the code and corrected the following:

- Your environment definition of `zebratitle` misses the ending part.
- This definition as well as the `\newfontfamily` should be moved to the preamble.
- Your `center` environment is now included into `zebratitle`.
- And your manual vertical skipping is replaced by automatic centering.
- Last, but not least, there's now `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf` and I removed the group causing strange `\baselineskip`.

This works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\newenvironment{zebratitle}{\begin{center}\changefontsizes{36pt}}{\end{center}}
\newfontfamily\myfunt[Ligatures=TeX]{Papyrus}

\begin{document}

  \extratitle{
    \begin{zebratitle}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \Huge\bfseries\myfunt Great Title
        \vfill
    \end{zebratitle}
  } 

  \title{Great Title}
  \author{The Author}
  \date{}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schweinebacke I've updated the most points, but I do not think the `\par` is actually necessary.

Comment: Yes, after the changes it is indeed not necessary.